# Firefox/Mozilla personas errors -- URL change?

Tags: firefox, themes

Has the location for Firefox/Mozilla personas changed? Looking at the error console I see:

```
GET https://addons.cdn.mozilla.net/en-US/firefox/_files/245568/firefoxtom.jpg [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 299ms]
```

Redownloading the persona gives:

```
GET https://addons.cdn.mozilla.net/user-media/addons/245568/firefoxtom.jpg [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 756ms]
```

For all my current personas, I only see the background color, not the image. Has something changed recently? Is there a workaround? FF 31. Thanks!

Comment: Calling LightweightThemeManager.updateCurrentTheme does return the new paths -- how do I go about updating all the personas?

Comment: This for [link](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/porsche-917-salzburg-1970/)  Here's the output from the error window -- it get a redirect, but gets redirected to the original place!

Comment: https://addons.cdn.mozilla.net/_files/245568/firefoxtom.jpg?1288084876
Request Method:     GET
Status Code:    HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Request Headers 09:25:39.000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0
Host:   addons.cdn.mozilla.net
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Language:    en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding:    gzip, deflate
Accept: image/png,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5

Comment: Response Headers Δ305ms
X-Frame-Options:    DENY
X-Backend-Server:   web7
Vary:   Accept-Language, User-Agent, X-Mobile
Strict-Transport-Security:  max-age=31536000
Server: nginx
Location:   https://addons.cdn.mozilla.net/en-US/firefox/_files/245568/firefoxtom.jpg?1288084876
Date:   Sun, 07 Sep 2014 15:25:41 GMT
Content-Type:   text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 0
Cache-Control:  max-age=31536000

Answer (score 0):

Hearing nothing, I'll assume it's a web server misconfiguration on Mozilla's part and that no one  cares. Just for posterity, here is the request/response that I tried to post in comments above, but that didn't look very good.

```
https://addons.cdn.mozilla.net/_files/245568/firefoxtom.jpg?1288084876
Request Method:     GET
Status Code:    HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Request Headers 09:25:39.000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0
Host:   addons.cdn.mozilla.net
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Language:    en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding:    gzip, deflate
Accept: image/png,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5
Response Headers Δ305ms
X-Frame-Options:    DENY
X-Backend-Server:   web7
Vary:   Accept-Language, User-Agent, X-Mobile
Strict-Transport-Security:  max-age=31536000
Server: nginx
Location:   https://addons.cdn.mozilla.net/en-US/firefox/_files/245568/firefoxtom.jpg?1288084876
Date:   Sun, 07 Sep 2014 15:25:41 GMT
Content-Type:   text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 0
Cache-Control:  max-age=31536000
```